# How to get values using jQuery from dropdown array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to go through a few `<tr>`s (I don’t know the exact number beforehand since they are generated on the fly), where I have a few dropdowns. The names of dropdowns are set as `item_size[]`, `item_set[]` and `item_quantity[]`. I need to get their value `onsubmit`.

I understand that I need to use each function here, like `$('tr.item').each(function(){` to go through them and then need to find a way to get values chosen in each of the three dropdowns.

Any idea here ?
Thanks.

```
<tr class="item">
    <td>some stuff</td>
    <td><select name = "item_size[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td><select name = "item_set[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td>some stuff</td>
    <td><select name = "item_quantity[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td>some stuff</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td>some stuff</td>
    <td><select name = "item_size[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td><select name = "item_set[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td>some stuff</td>
    <td><select name = "item_quantity[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td>some stuff</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td>some stuff</td>
    <td><select name = "item_size[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td><select name = "item_set[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td>some stuff</td>
    <td><select name = "item_quantity[]" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td>some stuff</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var inputs = new Array();
$("tr.item").each(function() {
    var tr_inputs = new Array();
    $(this).find("select").each(function() {
        tr_inputs[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });
    inputs.push(tr_inputs);
});
console.log(inputs);
```

You can retrieve the values for each item from the array `inputs`. Each item consists of 3 key value pairs for `item_size[]`, `item_set[]` and `item_quantity[]`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy I didn't get why you set name for select like 'item_size[]' i.e. with array brackets.
Instead of seting names, use id attribute like id ='item_size' and you have to set a 'id' or 'class' to your 'td' like

```
<td class = "itemsize"><select id= "item_size" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
    <td class = "itemset"><select id= "item_set" ...><option>...</option><option>...</option></select></td>
```

I assume your 'onsubumit' is a simple button click,
then you can get selected item of each dropdown list as:

```
var count =0, itemSize = new Array(), itemSet = new Array();    
$('#yourTableId tr').each(function(index) {

 itemSize[count] = $(this).find('.itemsize').find('#item_size:selected').val();
 itemSet[count] = $(this).find('.itemset').find('#item_set:selected').val();
count++;
}
```

Comment: That seems to suggest having multiple IDs with the same name on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as using the built-in function [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

```
var result = $('select').serializeArray();
```

You can manipulate the selector to suit, and once you have the data you can do what you like with it.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wnH4m/

**Edit**: this doesn't group your selects, so if that's what you need, then you're better off rolling your own as in Antony's answer. (You could parse the output of serializeArray(), but it may not be the best idea to loop over the DOM *and* over the dataset.)

Comment: But this is not grouped according to the item involved. In this case, every set of three selects (`item_size[]`, `item_set[]` and `item_quantity[]`) belongs to a single item.

Comment: True; I guess it depends on the desired format required by the OP — the question doesn't make it fully clear.